# How to return a value from the subprocess in python?

Tags: python, django

I am using django 1.11.
In the view.py file i am calling a subprocess like this:

```
def twitter_trend(request):
    output = call("python /home/imsaiful/PiroProject/pironews/feed/twitter/trends.py", shell=True)
    print(output)
    return HttpResponse(output, content_type='text/plain')
```

My trends.py file is given below which is calling by this process

```
import os
def sum():
    print("hello world")
    a = 5
    b = 3
    return a+b
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sum()
```

When I call this file it returns 0 by HTTP response.

How to return addition of a+b in the HttpResponse?

Comment: Are you sure you need to use `subprocess` to run the python script? For the example above, you should be able to do somthing like `from pironews.feed.twitter.trends import sum`, then `output = sum()` in your Django view.

Comment: Sir @Alasdair I am trying according to your instruction but I am getting this error from this method     File "/home/imsaiful/PiroProject/pironews/feed/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/imsaiful/PiroProject/pironews/feed/views.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pironews.feed.twitter.trends import sum
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pironews.feed'

Comment: I don't know the layout of your project, so I had to guess the correct import. Try `from .twitter.trends import sum` or `from feed.twitter.trends import sum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `check_output`:

```
def twitter_trend(request):
    output = check_output(["python",  "/home/imsaiful/PiroProject/pironews/feed/twitter/trends.py"])
    print(output)
    return HttpResponse(output, content_type='text/plain')
```

And use stdout for trends.py:

```
import os

def sum():
    print("hello world")
    a = 5
    b = 3
    return a+b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sum())
```

Comment: Why this very literally answers the question, using subprocess to call Python code from Python code is quite often not the simplest solution, cf alasdair's comment on the question.